# Configurar Delphi 10.1 Berlin Starter para desenvolvimento Android e iOS

Tags: delphi, delphi-berlin

consegui um estágio pra desenvolvedor delphi e assim que recebi a notícia de que avia sido aprovado nos testes, fui avisado também que o projeto em que eu seria alocado será um novo sistema mobile de um cliente da empresa que vou estagiar. Sendo assim me avisaram que eu deveria dar uma estudada e pra não chegar lá muito cru.

Então fiz o download dessa versão do Delphi que é gratuita e estou tentando configurar para desenvolvimento mobile, porém não consigo. Ele não tem as opções de Android ou iOS como vejo nos vídeos no youtube.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Na instalação, você selecionou a opção para instalar os componentes para desenvolvimento Android?

Comment: Mas não aparece essa opção pra mim na hora da instalação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, verifica se tem o java instalado e qual versão dele tem no computador, o bom é atualizar. Segundo, na hora que tu for instalar o delphi, tu coloca pra ele instalar o Android SDK, esse é o pacote de classes que vão usados pro desenvolvimento pra android

Comment: A opção de instalar o Android SKD não aparece pra mim na hora da instalação. Fiz o download da versão Delphi Berlin Starter.

Comment: @AlissonBoucinhas Então esse é o problema, na versão starter como é muito limitada, não tem como desenvolver pra mobile, apenas a partir da professional.

Comment: Ah, entendi! Enão devo baixar o Delphi Seattle ou o Berlin na versão professional?

Comment: Pode baixar qualquer um, desde que seja professional ou enterprise